# <Image source={require(" ")} /> not displaying correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, axios

Im confused that my Image is not being displayed.

This works but its a bit too static. I need a dynamic profile-picture update when uploading a file.

```
import picture from "../../images/public/600bc441b2b2b62c542bd135profilepicture.jpg"; 

 return(
        <div>
            <Image className={"profilepicture"} source={picture} alt={"pic"} />
        </div>
    )
```

So I implemented it with my Backend-Axios-Call like this:

```
    const [mapimages, setMapImages] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(API_BASE_URL + '/user/images', payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                const files = response.data.files[0];    
                const requireimg = require("../../images/public/" + files);
                setMapImages(<Image source={requireimg} alt={"TEXT"} />);
            } else {
                alert("error getting images");
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("DOWNLOAD: " + error);
        });

    }, []);


return(
    <div>
       {mapimages}
    </div>
)
```

Sadly I dont get the Images displayed. It shows the correct path to the File though.

This is the path in my image inspector:

```
<img alt="TEXT" class="profilepicture" source="/static/media/600bc441b2b2b62c542bd135profilepicture.8a22cb97.jpg">
```

and navigating
from

```
http://localhost:3000/#/profile
```

to

```
http://localhost:3000/static/media/600bc441b2b2b62c542bd135profilepicture.8a22cb97.jpg
```

also displays the Image.

I always get this: [image]

I'm clueless because this previously worked. I just forgot to push it to git :(

Comment: It is a static image, you don't need require.

Comment: @ATM That was the Issue. I mixed in some ReactNative syntax. oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to replace "source" with "src" inside your image tag